# AngularJS/Select2 add item programmatically and selecting that item is not working

Tags: angular-ui, ui-select2

I am new to using AngularJS and the select2 control (AngularUI) and am using the latest stable version of select2 (3.4.5).  I am trying to add an item programmatically through javascript to the list that the ui-select is using and selecting that item. For some reason, it updates the ng-model, but does not select the item from the dropdown visually.

Example here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/X1flkKxnDHVCgXHnnmE4?p=preview

As you will see, when you click "add yellow", it adds it to the dropdown, and sets the model `selectedColor` to be the correct color, however, it does not get updated visually on the `<select>`.  Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add `$scope.$Apply();` after adding new items to the list to Angular could render it correctly.

You can see an example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/66zQdJl1MvRIcx3qGCkz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Little hack for solving this problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Us35mGXkaOGGc3jHGdDf?p=preview

You just copy array by `angular.copy()`.

There are 2 examples. See versions block. First for strings and second for objects.